# ActiveRecord 6 without Rails (Multiple Databases)

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I'm aware that Rails 6.x now supports multiple database connections.  However, I am inheriting a codebase written without Rails, but I want to leverage the new feature available in ActiveRecord 6.  Looking through the AR gem, I was able to load the connections manually (set up environment as "default_env") and have `connects_to` running correctly on my model.

Where I am stuck is handling the connection switching.  I am going to assume that I will not be able to use the automatic switching (https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html#activating-automatic-connection-switching) since there is no Rack or Rails.  I can in `irb` do `Model.connected_to` correctly, but I'm not sure that I would be able to use that on `find` methods without manually defining those methods.

Is there a way to set up the automatic switching without the `ActiveRecord::Middleware::DatabaseSelector` or some other way to leverage that class?

**UPDATE**

database.yml

```
connection: &conn
  username: ***
  password: ***
  adapter: mysql2
  host: ***
  pool: 5

default_env:
  db1:
    <<: *conn
    database: db1
  db2:
    <<: *conn
    database: db2
```

```rb
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
#uses db1 connection
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
connects_to database: { writing: :db2, reading: :db2 }
end
```

Comment: Are you trying to have 1 model connect to 2 databases or individual models connecting to their own databases?

Comment: collections of models connecting to their own databases.